# How to remove an item in Bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash, arguments, command-line-arguments

I would like to pass all script arguments to the `foo` function, and if the first argument is `something`, pass all the rest arguments to the `bar` function.

I implemented this like that:

```
foo() {
  if [ "$1" = 'something' ]; then
    args=("$@")
    unset args[0]
    bar $args
  fi
}

foo $@
```

Is that possible to simplify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `shift`

```
foo(){ 
  if [[ $1 == 'something' ]]; then
    shift
    bar "$@" 
  fi
}

foo "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks! Are the quotes really required in `foo "$@"` and `bar "$@"`?

Comment: @MishaMoroshko it's not necessary but you should always quote your variables unless you explicitly have a reason not to.  Most of the time you *don't* want word splitting.  I didn't quote the `$1` because you don't have word splitting problems inside of `[[ ]]`. I don't believe the same applies to `[ ]` though

Comment: @SiegeX You should still quote the `$1` because it'll fail if there are no parameters passed `[: ==: unary operator expected`.

Comment: @nicerobot that is only an issue with `[ ]`, not `[[ ]]`. This is why I said in my previous comment *I don't believe the same applies to `[ ]` though*

Comment: @SiegeX D'oh! Darn selective perception. My eyes didn't even register the `[[ ]]`. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the `args` array for anything else in `foo`, you can avoid it entirely as in SiegeX's answer.  If you need `args` for some other reason, what you are doing is the simplest way.

There is a bug in your code.  When you call `bar`, you're only passing the first element of `args`.  To pass all elements, you need to do this:

```
bar "${args[@]}"
```